# Can you change labels randomly in MNIST with Tensorflows download?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, mnist

Does anyone know if its possible to change some of the labels (maybe 5%) in MNIST'd Train data randomly? I would just move them but Tensorflows API doesn't seem to have the option.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

tf.enable_v2_behavior()
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train[:50%]', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that will modify the label with a certain probability, and map it over the dataset.

For example, here is a function that will change a label with a 0.05% chance to a random integer between 0 and 9.

```
def change_label_with_prob(label, prob=0.05):
    return tf.cond(
        tf.random.uniform(()) > prob,
        lambda: label,
        lambda: tf.random.uniform((), 0, 10, dtype=tf.int64),
    )

ds_train = ds_train.map(lambda x,y:(x,change_label_with_prob(y)))
```